# Tcp connection between iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, ios11, multipeer-connectivity

As for now, I'm using multi peer connectivity between iOS devices communication in same network. Facing major problem in connectivity, its getting disconnected often. So would like to move different approach.

Someone pls suggest me to achieve this in some other concepts.

Comment: when new client connect to your host, store that client object in array(Host side).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem programmatically by detecting dropped connections and attempting to reconnect whenever a connection is unexpectedly lost. Some other considerations are:

- Multipeer connectivity will not work when the app is running in the background
- Multipeer connectivity tends to become unreliable if you are trying to maintain a connection between 6+ devices

If you are determined to find a replacement for Multipeer Connectivity, then we'd need to know more about what you're trying to accomplish. If you're trying to make a game, for example, I might suggest [Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/). You could also look into [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/).